# Gravitational waves from an oscillating mass

Tags: gravitational-waves

If you drill a hole through the earth and drop a mass down it, it will oscillate back and forth as it moves through the hole from one end to the other.  Does this motion create gravitational waves (I don't care how strong they are, but does this system in principle emit gravitational waves)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No gravitational waves will be emitted - but its only because you chose the one 'orbit' - that with an infinite eccentricity - to launch your mass into. Other orbits like that of a satellite around the Earth generate gravitational waves as they show a quadrupole moment.

A rock dropped straight down a tunnel is in an orbit of sorts. Its not a Keplerian one as the rock sees a different mass as it approaches the centre of the Earth. I am ignoring the spin of the Earth in this answer.

Your case - where the mass simply moves up and down is only dipole and will not produce gravitational waves.

The earth does not damp out the waves - in fact it also radiates some waves but much much less than the lighter object (which itself radiates little), due to the fact that it is dragged in a very small circular motion by the mass that is in orbit.

The Earth generates 200 watts of gravitational waves in its orbit around the Sun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any object (no matter how small or big) with mass that *accelerates* (translationally or rotationally) will produce gravitational waves. As you anticipated, in this case it will be *very very very* weak.

Correction (Credits for users *Timaeus* and *hsnee59*):
The acceleration needs to be *asymmetric* in the mentioned scenarios in order to produce gravitational waves from an oscillating mass.

Comment: Not quite correct. If you drive a spherically symmetric shell inwards and outwards in a radial fashion then it accelerates, but it doesn't radiate.

Comment: Let me stress that, as Timaeus said, it is the *asymmetry* of acceleration that produces gravitational waves.

Comment: Thanks Timaeus and hsnee for the corrections. I should have been more careful. I would like to edit my response to better reflect these points.

Comment: But the question which is still not answered is if the case mentioned by the author is truly symmetric in nature which might be disputable at this point. What do you guys think?

Comment: My guess was there were no waves because in the earth's frame, the object is accelerating but in the object's frame the earth is accelerating so how would the waves know which mass is accelerating?

Comment: I would say one way to unequivocally prove whether it does or not (if we are to get technical) would be to calculate the third time derivative of the quadrupole of the system's energy-stress tensor. If it is non-zero, the system is indeed emitting gravitational waves.